# How to recall old learning - like humans

Tags: machine-learning

When humans learn something and do not use that for some time, we tend to forget it. However, good thing is if needed in future, and we see the data again we do not need to learn it from scratch. We just recall it.
For a machine learning model, can someone suggest how to build an architecture which does this. I understand the concept of LSTM but that is a very basic unit. For cases like NLP where we need large models, I am seeking suggestions here, how to solve this.

Comment: Machines do not forget though, so I don't understand how this concept makes sense when talking about a machine.

Comment: @liakoyras In the context of machine learning with RNNs it does. RNNs (including LSTMs) have great problems remembering things.

Comment: Imho it's not necessarily the correct way to copy human behaviour. People rely too much on the analogy between NN and brain, but it's really [not the same thing](https://www.noemamag.com/ai-and-the-limits-of-language/).

Answer (score 2):

[Memory-augmented Neural Networks](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v48/santoro16.html) (MANNs) sound kind-of similar to what you are describing.  In this architecture, the network acts as a controller that can read and write from a block of external long-term memory.  MANNs are still in the early stages of research and development; last I heard, they were very difficult to train but show some promising results when successfully trained.

Here's a paper that applies MANNs to some NLP problems: https://aclanthology.org/D17-3005/